# mkdir: cannot create directory: Function not implemented

Tags: ssh, filesystems, terminal, scp

I am in college and have to submit my cs homework from a school Linux machine, but I like doing the homework on my laptop (Mac). So instead of copying my files over every time, then submitting them, I decided to make a script to do it for me using `scp` and `ssh`. When I tested my script the first time, the `scp` command created the directory `hw3` on the other machine. The next time I tested it, it created the directory `hw4`. Both directories had my program files in them. Since both directories only created for testing, I deleted them both using `rm -r`. But here is where the problem arises.

Through later testing of my script and other debugging, I found that I now cannot create any file or folder named hw3 or hw4 on the other machine while connected to it via `ssh`. I can create a folder named anything else, just not `hw3` or `hw4`. I can't make them via `mkdir`, `mv`, `cp`, or touch, making me think there is something wrong with the filesystem. However, I can make `hw3` and `hw4` files in the parent directory. Nobody I have talked to knows what this is and has never seen it before, and Googling the issue hasn't turned up any results.

At my school there are many different machines I can log onto and I tried several, but the problem persists on all of them, which makes sense since I am working from a network drive (SDRIVE in the path). To get the script working, I used the workaround of just making it create `hww#` instead of `hw#`, but I would still really like to know what is going on and how to fix it.

This is my terminal output from when I log on via `ssh` and my commands.

```
Last login: Tue Mar  3 11:40:18 2015 from r03ane3md.device.mst.edu
You are currenly one of 7 users on this host!
ane3md@rc07xcs213:~$ cd SDRIVE/cs1510
ane3md@rc07xcs213:~/SDRIVE/cs1510$ ls -l
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 ane3md mst_users 0 Mar  3 12:01 hw1
drwxr-xr-x 2 ane3md mst_users 0 Feb 21 21:37 hw2
drwxr-xr-x 2 ane3md mst_users 0 Mar  3 11:59 hww3
ane3md@rc07xcs213:~/SDRIVE/cs1510$ mkdir hw3
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘hw3’: Function not implemented
ane3md@rc07xcs213:~/SDRIVE/cs1510$ touch hw3
touch: cannot touch ‘hw3’: Function not implemented
ane3md@rc07xcs213:~/SDRIVE/cs1510$ mv hww3 hw3
mv: failed to access ‘hw3’: Function not implemented
ane3md@rc07xcs213:~/SDRIVE/cs1510$
```

EDIT: As requested, running "stat -f ~/SDRIVE" outputs the following:

```
ane3md@rc07xcs213:~$ stat -f ~/SDRIVE
  File: "/usr/local/home/ane3md/SDRIVE"
    ID: 0        Namelen: 4096    Type: fuseblk
Block size: 4096       Fundamental block size: 4096
Blocks: Total: 0          Free: 0          Available: 0
Inodes: Total: 314572031  Free: 66717154
```

EDIT - WORKAROUND: I did some snooping, and I found that our school uses dfshack (you can google it on github) to link Windows and unix/linux filesystems, and was made by a student here, so naturally, it has bugs. Apparently I found one of them. I also did some more testing, and found that the following process sort of works to allow me to create the directories again. I have a Mac, so I'm not sure if this would work for Windows.

1. Map the network drive to Mac OS so you can access it via Finder
2. Create via Finder the directory that couldn't be created before.
3. Connect to the remote machine via ssh and navigate to the directory where that you couldn't create the folders or files in.
4. Type `mv dirCreatedViaFinder newName`
5. You can now create directories and files named whatever could not be created before, but there is a drawback. If you `rm -r newName`, you now cannot create `newName` files and folders. So I think the whole issue is caused by removing directories.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `~/SDRIVE` directory is mounted as a [fuse](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/) filesystem which means that the filesystem operations are handled by some userspace program, not by the kernel. Those errors are coming from the filesystem implementation, which could be anything at all and is probably some kind of site-custom software.

This is one of those times where you're probably going to have to go bug your sysadmins and ask them what is wrong. One would *guess* that there is either something they need to fix, possibly just with your account, or that this is some weird in-house way to deal with accidental deletion.